# Click through positioned div with z-index to submit button underneath

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index

I have:

```
<div style="bottom:0; left:0; right:0; position:fixed; z-index:50; display:inline-block;">
    <div style="margin:auto; width:500px; background-color:#90C553; -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px; -moz-border-radius-topright:5px; border:1px solid #CCC; text-align:center;">
        <h3 style="font-size:17px; color:#0072A7; padding:10px 15px;">example</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and if there is something on the same level as this div, then div overflows it.

Is there a way to fix this problem without changing entire design structure?

**UPDATE**

Space for outer div stretches from side to side 100%. Since it has z-index property it overflows everything that is below. So if I have for example button which during scrolling will be below this div it woun't be pushable.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. Could you explain the "div overflows it" part please?

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. You want to be able to click a button that is rendered under a `<div>`.

Comment: Yes, but without CSS3 or html5. Only basics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have [**made a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DC9MF/) which I think shows the problem and a solution. You may need to resize the `HTML` section so that the `<submit>` button is underneath the "example" `<div>` with the green background.

The solution I have used is the CSS3-UI [`pointer-events`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#pointer-events) property. There is one drawback though, in that it is not supported in IE or Opera. According to [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/pointer-events)
is works in Firefox 3.6+, Safari 3+, Chrome 4+.

I have tested this in Chrome12 and Firefox4 and I can click on the `<submit>` button under the `<div>`

**Edit:** Well you can either re-design the site or hide the `<div>` completely for IE/Opera. However, if you can use JavaScript (which I guess you must be since `position:fixed` does not work in IE without it), there are a couple of options I can think of:

1. Fade out/fade in the `<div>` when the mouse is over it
2. Get the mouse co-ordinates and find the `<input>` underneath and then programmatically *click* the button (see http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

**Edit 2: [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DC9MF/4/)** to work with IE. This solution needs jQuery but it could be probably done without a library. You will need to play with the CSS `position` to get an `<input>` under the positioned `<div>`.

**Note:** This has been covered before [Click through div with an alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793204/click-through-div-with-an-alpha-channel) and [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: That's great and everything, but this is shop design not some small project and since it's a shop and there is a variety of customers who also probably use IE and Opera it's not a good solution.

Comment: I have got it working in IE6 with JavaScript (well jQuery) implementing option 2 in my answer.

Comment: I did your solution as a fallback and tweeked my little bit. http://jsbin.com/amoze4